# Why i cant access the classes of my Eclipse plugin at Runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runtime, eclipse-classpath

I’m developing an Eclipse plugin, `com.simple.plugin`, with the following structure:
[image: Plugin Structure]

The problem is that **during runtime I cant access the classes of my own plugin**.
For example if I do the following code inside the SampleHandler.java:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("com.simple.handlers.SampleHandler");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simple.handlers.SampleHandler cannot be found by com.simple.plugin_1.0.0.qualifier*
```

My manifest runtime option for classpath have the root of the plug-in, so I dont know what is wrong!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You need to show us a more complete example.

Comment: What i did was simply create: a plug-in project-> use the template hello command. Then it generates the structures that i revealed. Then add the code line Class cls = Class.forName("PluginName.SampleHandler") to some class in the plugin. And i think you wil get the same error when trying to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SampleHander` class is in the `com.simple.plugin.handlers` package **not** the `com.simple.handlers` package. So the correct code is:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.simple.plugin.handlers.SampleHandler");
```

You must always specify the full **package** name of the class you want.

Comment: oh god... Tks for the help, i was always thiking it was a classpath error, and it turns out its the same error as always: me :D

Comment: I checked this twice ;D

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse plugins runs each with an own class loader. Thus you won't be able to dynamically load any class from an other bundle.

For this kind of problem there is a Buddy system in Eclipse osgi. You have to change your parent project buddy policy in the manifest.mf file:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: Registered
```

To make the classes from an other plugin project be aviable to your parent project add this to your manifest.mf file.

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: {NAME OF THE PARENT PLUGIN}
```

For example:

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: de.myname.myplugin
```

Now you will be able to load your class from both plugins.

See also here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements

Comment: There only appears to be one plugin involved here so this doesn't apply.

Comment: yes it is only a plugin involved (com.simple.plugin), and i was trying during runtime of that plugin call some of his classes.